# d3js - How to Override the text in the nth position

Tags: d3.js

```
<ul class = "items">
  <li> Item 1</li>
  <li> Item 2</li>
  <li> Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

What is wrong with following code, unit test is failing?

```
<script>
    d3.select('li:nth-child(2n)').html('Hello World').style('color', 'Blue').classed('big', true);
  </script>
```

Comment: Your code looks correct. Could you show us your unit test and also how you put the code together? Maybe you are running your JS before the DOM has been built? Do you get any Console errors?

Comment: Dude, don't post your code in the comments. Edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

As  Hubert Grzeskowiak said your code is working fine. Just follow the order in which you are trying to manipulate

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<ul class = "items">
  <li> Item 1</li>
  <li> Item 2</li>
  <li> Item 3</li>
</ul>

<script>
    d3.select('li:nth-child(2n)').html('Hello World').style('color', 'Blue').classed('big', true);
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this, if you want to update the 3rd li item.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<ul class = "items">
  <li> Item 1</li>
  <li> Item 2</li>
  <li> Item 3</li>
</ul>

<script>
d3.select('li:nth-child(3)').html('Hello World').style('color', 'blue').classed('big', true);

 </script>
```